# Image processing for extracting regions of book pages that are covered by text

Tags: image-processing

Is it possible to apply Mathematica's image processing capabilities for extracting regions of book pages that are covered by text, e.g. by a combination of blurring and binarizing, or better? Also the faster the better.

Here is a possible input and (approximate) output.

[image]
[image]

Comment: @rasher Bluring, binarizing (as mentioned), and various filters mentioned under segmentation analysis. Unfortunately, the results are no good (not worth posting).

Answer (score 6):

If you want a quick&dirty method, `CornerFilter` might be a good place to start:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVRea.png"];
corners = CornerFilter[img, 2];
mask = DeleteSmallComponents[
   Closing[MorphologicalBinarize[corners, {0.2, 1}*10^-4], 
    DiskMatrix[2]]];

HighlightImage[img, mask]
```

[image]